# SharePoint REST API returns incomplete content of file during downloading

Tags: rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I work on application for fetching and downloading SharePoint data. For every folder in SharePoint I can get the list of all files inside given folder by using next SharePoint REST API endpoint:

`/_api/web/GetFolderById('<folder_guid>')/Files`

The expected size and guid is provided for every file so I can use them when I want to download the file. Then I use the next endpoint from SharePoint REST API in order to actually get file content:

`/_api/web/GetFileById('<file_guid>')/$value`

From time to time when I download the file I get less data than expected: size of downloaded data is just different from the value I obtain while getting the properties list of files. However when I try to get its content again it can be successfully downloaded (size of downloaded data is equal the expected value) or I can get another incomplete data.

I verified that the first endpoint (one used to get properties of all files in the folder) returns the correct file size. The problem is in the call of the second one.

I see that there is ["transfer-encoding"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding) header with "chunked" value in response. So when my http client performs chunked data download and if zero chunk is received at some point then we reached the end of the body [by definition](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-4.1). So it looks like in some cases SharePoint either returns the incomplete data or zero chunks when they should not be sent.

What can be the reason of such strange behavior? Is it a know issue?

Answer (score 1):

We actually also see this, strange behaviour, many files are just small aspx files, about 3-4kb and they are constantly smaller by 15% and more than appears in file propertis. We're also using REST API and this is really frustrating. All those strange bugs in Sharepoint Online are very annoying.

Answer (score -2):

this is an interesting topic... are those files large? like over 1GB? It would seem that chunk file download is not supported way in SP Online. Better option is to user RPC. Please see this links for examples:
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/184789/download-large-files-from-sharepoint-online

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/03e55d41-1daf-46a5-b61d-2d80139123f4/download-large-files-using-rest?forum=sharepointdevelopment

https://piyushksingh.com/2016/08/15/download-large-files-from-sharepoint-online/

You could also check the MS Graph API if maybe will work better for this case

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-get-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

... I hope this will be of any help

Comment: Thanks for you response, Adam. Actually I know that MS Graph API usage is recommended approach but my application is basically using SharePoint REST endpoints at the moment. I just try to figure out why data downloading fails from time to time or what am I doing wrong.

Comment: As for the size of files then I see the problem both for relatively small files (e. g. I have several 50MB files) and for files bigger than 8GB.
I don't use C#. Instead of this I have custom c++ based http client component in my code which has been reliably working for a really long time.

Comment: And are those files large or small? Finding out what might be the problem that happens 'from time to time's may be hard :-). Maybe this are some connection timeout for some chunks with data or something like this. What about this RPC approach? Is this possible for You to check? Maybe it will be more stabke

Comment: Ok.. sorry, I assumed You were using c#. Thanks for the info about the file size.

Comment: This is very annoying bug of Sharepoint (https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/5247), it hurts migration and backup services in Sharepoint. Workaround using RPC is not possible with OAuth and basic authentication will come into end of life for office 365 in October 2020.