# Sharepoint Graph API download file from Document library that are not listed as drive ("Site Pages" and others)

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I'm trying to find a way in Sharepoint Graph API how download file in Document library that are not listed as drive (Site Pages and others). 
If I enumerating lists, I see "Site Pages" in lists:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/<site id>/lists
```

I even can enumerate item in list :

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/<site id>/lists/<list id>/items
```

But I can't find a way to get a content (download) those items (files).
All available url to download file (get content) are next:

```
GET /drives/{drive-id}/items/{item-id}/content
GET /groups/{group-id}/drive/items/{item-id}/content
GET /me/drive/root:/{item-path}:/content
GET /me/drive/items/{item-id}/content
GET /sites/{siteId}/drive/items/{item-id}/content
GET /users/{userId}/drive/items/{item-id}/content
```

Doesn't provides an ability to get the content.
I can't find a way to get drive id for list, and there's no url to get content from list (even if it's documents library).

Please advise.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call the following endpoints to retrieve:

1. all document libraries on a site
2. items in a document library (from root)
3. download the content of an item

This may not be the most efficient set of queries but I successfully tested in my lab tenant.

1. https://graph.microsoft.com/(version)/sites/(site-id)/drives
2. https://graph.microsoft.com/(version)/sites/(site-id)/drive/(drive-id)/root/children
3. https://graph.microsoft.com/(version)/sites/(site-id)/drive/(drive-id)/items/(item-id)/content

Comment: Note that I specified site-id as (hostname),(site-guid),(web-guid) rather than using relative URL syntax.  I've seen small differences between the two in past.

Comment: Thanks, what's the difference that you saw?

Comment: Here is a question with an example.  Getting drive / file information yields a 400 Bad Request with relative URL syntax but works fine with GUIDs syntax.  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61597024/issues-getting-drive-information-when-using-the-graph-api-with-a-server-relative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61597024/issues-getting-drive-information-when-using-the-graph-api-with-a-server-relative)

Comment: Thanks Brian, I see another strange issue, don't know to what it can be related, maybe you know the answer :) : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61678111/sharepoint-graph-api-strange-behaviour-while-trying-to-get-download-link-for-a-f

Comment: Thanks Brian! This three-step approach was very valuable for me. In Graph API docs, there is nothing about downloading files under Sites nor Lists. I didn't realize I had to look for Drives and Items.

Answer (score -1):

The drive resource represents a user's OneDrive or a document library in SharePoint. while site page is a page library, not document library, this is why it's not returned in drive request.

We suggest you get the file using SharePoint Rest API.

- [Working with files by using REST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-folders-and-files-with-rest#working-with-files-by-using-rest)

Comment: Thanks. But there's an issue with REST : https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/5247  and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59737754/sharepoint-rest-api-returns-incomplete-content-of-file-during-downloading - they are suggesting to use Graph API, so it's kind a ping pong.