# Get a file from SharePoint Online using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-files

While learning graph API, I was trying to get a file from a SharePoint document library using Microsoft Graph API.

I first tried by accessing files in `Documents` from `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/tenant.sharepoint.com`

by doing this GET request:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/tenant.sharepoint.com/drive/root:/Test:/children
```

Everything worked great, I then tried accessing documents from another site within the same tenant. I told my self it was the same pathway while following the Microsoft docs.

I first did a test request to be sure i can first access to my site; here is what I did;

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/tenant.sharepoint.com:/sites/ObserveTestSite
```

On executing that query i got a `200 OK` response.

Secondly I then tried accessing the drive `Documents` here is what i did;

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/tenant.sharepoint.com:/sites/ObserveTestSite:/drive
```

again everything worked fine.

I then used the `root` relation followed by the name of the directory and then the `children` relation; and this was my request:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/tenant.sharepoint.com:/sites/ObserveTestSite:/drive/root:/Test:/children
```

But while executing that, I'm getting `Bad Request - 400 - 96ms`

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Can you re-test using the failing scenario URL and share the request ID and UTC timestamp?  Also re-test but change to using [hostname,site-guid, web-guid]? I have seen an issue with using relative URL where the parser isn't able to go beyond the "drive" or "drives" element and am bringing it up to the relevant PMs.  See here for another question in the same space: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61597024/issues-getting-drive-information-when-using-the-graph-api-with-a-server-relative

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @BrianT.JackettMSFT 

Here is the output:
`"date": "2020-06-16T07:46:56"`
`"request-id": "271e1161-734a-4684-82f0-6eeb18f842b2"`

The second alternative using [hostname,site-guid, web-guid] works great!

Comment: Thank you for providing that information. I'll take a look at the logs. I've seen this personally and also reported from a few other people. I have an open conversation with the API owner looking into this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have the same issue when using site relative url to specify the specific site.

Now I'm using siteId instead and everything works as expected:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/zheguo.sharepoint.com,91a47a59-db5e-4d17-a689-479ee8905533,274459c9-4c96-42bf-9b96-838ffa387aaa/drive/root:/X:/children
```