# How to download a file from a SharePoint though a web site button?

Tags: sharepoint, integration, sharepoint-online

I have a web page that has a button and a SharePoint library.

Once the user clicks the download button, the document will be downloaded from SharePoint with a watermark of the user trying to download this file.

Additionally, I need to manage who can access or download the file.

Therefore, the **main points to consider** are:

- User authentication to the SharePoint document library
- Pulling the document from the website itself
- Watermark feature

Thus, what is the most effective practice to achieve that and what should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

oh man, this is really an open and not quite detailed question . Could you provide more context? what language are you using? have you already tried something and what is failing?

For now, the only help I may provide you is just general info :

> User authentication to the SharePoint document library

if you are extending SharePoint or M365 with a SPFx solution you do not need to worry on auth. If it is totally aside I would recommend checking

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth/auth-concepts
- I would strongly recommend checking [microsoft-graph-toolkit](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-toolkit) there is a [mgt-login component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/toolkit/components/login)

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/toolkit/components/login

again here I would also recommend using MS Graph and endpoint like `https://graph.microsoft.com/(version)/sites/(site-id)/drive/(drive-id)/items/(item-id)/content`

- I guess this is a very similar topic: [Sharepoint Graph API download file from Document library that are not listed as drive ("Site Pages" and others)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61499357/sharepoint-graph-api-download-file-from-document-library-that-are-not-listed-as)

> Watermark feature

as for this I would take a look at Microsoft 365 sensitivity labels feature and read more about it here

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/sensitivity-labels?view=o365-worldwide#what-sensitivity-labels-can-do

I hope this will be of any help. For sure it is a good start

Comment: Hello Adam, I really appreciate your response.
I just wanted a general idea of how it may be achieved and you provided me with the necessary info.
Thank you